# Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit/YogaKit.modulemap' not found

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

i'm created new project in react-native and i'm trying to build in xcode but it was coming fatal error

fatal error: module map file '/Users/gis00109/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sam-capwmdorzbxfzphhezjlrwcbyxyp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit/YogaKit.modulemap' not found

Answer (score 2):

Steps to solve:

- Go to Xcode -> click target -> build settings
- Search for **VALID_ARCHS**
- write "arm64 armv7 x86_64" (without quotes) in that
- clean and rebuild

Comment: i didnt found VALID_ARCHS

Answer (score 0):

the problem could be that you opened up .xcodeproj instead of .xcworkspace .

Answer (score -1):

After trying every solution on the internet, this worked for me.

```
cd ios && pod install && cd ..
```

then

```
npx react-native link
```

or

```
yarn react-native link
```