# `YogaKit.modulemap not found` prevents iOS build

Tags: ios, react-native

I had to upgrade React Native (RN), to allow builds using Xcode `Version 12.5 (12E262)`. That upgrade left Android builds broken, until I upgraded again. Now Xcode will not build again. I'm here to upgrade React Native and fundamentally fix the build process for both OSs, and I'm all out of upgrade versions of React Native.

I'm aware of and have tried suggestions in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63261150/1818189):

1. Restarting didn't work nor did it change anything.
2. The CocoaPods and Podfile both target version `10.0`.
3. There is no section, `project`, in the `Podfile`, but if I add the recommended line, the error remains.
4. Attempting to open `.xcworkspace` in place of `xcodeproj` removes the option to build altogether.

I also tried the solution from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66684398/1818189).

I have noticed something strange lately. A couple of weeks ago the app was building fine for Apple and the popup terminal was the same as always. Now the popup terminal looks like the new terminal message when running the app for a simulator. It's the new Metro simulator:

[image: Welcome to Metro!]

Oddly, reverting packages changes nothing. I rested the project by reverting `package.json`, and `yarn.lock` followed by removing `node_modules`, running `yarn`, then `cd ios && pod update`. The same Metro terminal message shows regardless of RN version in `package.json`.

Is there a hack to fix for iOS builds? Is there a version of RN that works well for Apple and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

For me, adding the following to Podfile was necessary: `{ 'Flipper' => '0.91.1' }`.  Nothing else suggested seems to work.  I found the answer [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28503).